# CI (CodeIgniter) Active Record table name with spaces

Tags: database, codeigniter, activerecord

I have a codeigniter project where I try to connect with codeigniter's active record to a MSSQL database that has spaces in the table names. I have no problems with normal tables, but I can't figure out how I should escape the spaces...

I do the following:

```
$this->mssql = $this->load->database('mssql', TRUE);
$query = $this->mssql->get('SomeDatabase.dbo.Some Table Spaces');
```

CodeIgniter fails in the second line saying there is a problem with "Spaces" (because Table will be considered an alias I guess).

Is there any way to escape the spaces so I can connect to this table ? Please don't suggest renaming the table, because I obviously do not have that choice. The only alternative I can think of is creating a view with a decent name, but I would like to avoid that if possible.

Does anyone have experience with this problem and does there even exist a clean solution to this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

My database is Mysql, I create a table name "table test", using the query statement below will work:

```
$this->db->get(`table test`);
```